# Licence error using TypeLevelAspect (Composite Aspects) in PostSharp Express 4.3

Tags: c#, types, aop, postsharp, aspect

I have PostSharp Express 4.3 and I'm using `TypeLevelAspect` on a class. When I build, I get this error:

> License error. MyProject.dll uses non-licensed features (Composite Aspects). Please visit http://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp. PostSharp version: 4.3.30.0 The installed user license is: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".

I spoke to Tony on Technical Support, and he advised that **all** features of PostSharp should be available in 4.3 Express, and that this is likely a bug.

PostSharp, please assist.

Comment: Hello, I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. Could you please share a project which reproduces it?

Comment: @AntonínProcházka I've emailed a simple example project to you (via Zuzana). Please let me know you've received it in case my work email blocks it.

Comment: Hello, yes, we have received it and we'll let you know as soon as a bug fix has been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and it is fixed since PostSharp 4.3.33 and 5.0.24.